# Wordpress - Buddypress plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, buddypress

I want to hide sub-nav in profile settings

[image]

I hide sub-nav comment "wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-settings\bp-settings-loader.php"

```
// Add General Settings nav item
    $sub_nav[] = array(
        'name'            => __( 'General', 'buddypress' ),
        'slug'            => 'general',
        'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
        'parent_slug'     => $this->slug,
        'screen_function' => 'bp_settings_screen_general',
        'position'        => 10,
        'user_has_access' => bp_core_can_edit_settings()
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sub-nav item are you referring to?   If you want to remove the Settings menu option entirely you can do this in a plugin or functions.php

```
function my_admin_bar_mod(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'my-account-settings' );
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render','my_admin_bar_mod');
```

To remove just the Profile option under Settings use this instead:

```
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'my-account-settings-profile' );
```

UPDATE:

The following code will remove the General tab; I believe that is what you want. Correct?  This code does that but I am seeing a problem. It might be a rewrite problem on my dev site where the Settings tab causes a 4040 error.  Can you try this on your site and let me know?

```
function mcs_bp_remove_nav() {
    global $bp;
    bp_core_remove_subnav_item( $bp->settings->slug, 'general' );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'mcs_bp_remove_nav', 99);
```

Finally:

This code is needed in addition to the above.  It changes Settings to point to the Email tab. It was defaulting to General and since that was removed we see a 404.  This hook must fire earlier than the code that removes 'general'.

```
function mcs_bp_change_settings() {
    global $bp;
    // point setting to Email page (aka 'notifications')
    $args = array(  'parent_slug' => 'settings',
        'screen_function' => 'bp_core_screen_notification_settings',
        'subnav_slug' => 'notifications'
    );
    bp_core_new_nav_default( $args );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav','mcs_bp_change_settingst', 5);
```

Comment: Thanks.I disabled "General" and "Delete Account" sub-nav items. i do not want to disable settings menu. Is there a way to disable sub-nav item without commenting "wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-settings\bp-settings-loader.php" file

Comment: Yes there is; but based on your question and the image you provided, it isn't clear to me what sub-nav items you are referring to.  Are you trying to get rid of the General tab?  The tern sub-nav is confusing me.

Comment: I think I now understand what you want; I updated my answer. Please let me know if this works and if you see the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Final update (I think).  The last bit of code is needed to point settings to a new location since the general tab is now removed.  That fixed my 404 error.

Comment: Thanks Billk. That works fine. I'm new to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the sub-navigation in profile settings in BuddyPress, you can use custom CSS code.

Open your theme's CSS file. This file is usually named "style.css" and is located in your theme's directory.

```
Add the following code at the end of the CSS file:
/* Hide sub-navigation in BuddyPress profile settings */
.buddypress #item-nav {
    display: none;
}
```

You can even [BuddyPress addons](https://wbcomdesigns.com/plugins/buddypress/) for more easy work